# Como criar regex que aceite somente caracteres sem acentos

Tags: javascript, regex

No meu formulário `html`, tenho o campo "nome".
Nesse campo, quero permitir que o campo aceite somente caracteres sem acentos.
Como fazer essa validação utilizando Regex?

Não quero uma função, quero colocar um tipo de atributo no campo que bloqueie acentos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode utilizar o atributo [`pattern`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) do `input`, utilizando a regex `[A-Za-z ]*`...

```html
<form action="...">

  <input name="username" id="username" type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z ]*" title="Somente letras sem acento">

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Criei um regex da seguinte forma:

```
/[a-zA-Z ]/
```